# Gradle 6.8 to 7 version update in a spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradlew, gradle-wrapper

```
d:\myProject>gradlew build --warning-mode all

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
Property 'options.compilerArgumentProviders.apt$0.name' is not annotated with an input or 
output annotation. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. 
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks 
for more details.
Property 'options.compilerArgumentProviders.apt$0.publicType' is not annotated with an 
input or output annotation. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. 
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks
for more details.
```

I have tried removing the **generic plugin (id "net.ltgt.apt") and the IntelliJ (id "net.ltgt.apt-idea") plugin** as suggested by *@Bjørn Vester(https://www.linkedin.com/in/bjornvester/)*, but the code is giving same error.

I am trying to update gradle from 6.8 to 7.5 version.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first,
As  *@Bjørn Vester* said you need to remove the the below lines from `build.gradle`

```
    id "net.ltgt.apt-eclipse" version "0.21"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.21"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.21"
```

and add eclipse support by adding below line,

```
   id "com.diffplug.eclipse.apt" version "3.36.2"
```

and also update the version of
`id "com.diffplug.eclipse.apt"` to **latest**.

As on the date of writing this answer the version was **3.36.2**